# Using ternary operator with JSS and Material-UI in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I want to be able to use a certain CSS style depending on some rules.

I'm using this example just to simplify it.

```
const num = 3

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    color: [num <= 5 ? "red" :"blue"]
  }
});
```

The color should be red but the output is not what I'm trying to achieve. In fact, it only render blue no matter what I set the number to be.
Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Add more details. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve and atleast tell what you've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The color value should be a string instead of a string array. Change to

```js
color: num <= 5 ? 'red' : 'blue'
```

To fix your issue.

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking about making it a string array. Removing it did fix it. Thank you.